# Why is this second recursive factorial function wrong

Tags: recursion, factorial

So the first solution is the correct one, but the second one is giving me the same answer as the first one in every case I have tried. It felt to me like the second solution should work intuitively but it also seems wrong. Can someone explain why it is wrong?

```py
def factorial(n):
  if n in [0, 1]:
    return 1
  else:
    return n * factorial(n-1)

print(factorial(4))

def factorial2(n):
  while n >= 0:
    return n * factorial(n-1)

print(factorial2(4))
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why do you expec the other one to work different?

Comment: Think about what cases factorial is defined for and what cases the second method does not cover.

Comment: Note that your second function is called `factorial2`, and it makes a call to `factorial`. This is not a recursive call. It's a call to the function defined just above. Replace `return n * factorial(n-1)` with `return n * factorial2(n-1)`, and then it will cease to work, as you expect.

Comment: @Stef thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I should probably name my functions more uniquely so I don't accidentally call the wrong one like this.